# How to wait for the service to load before starting the activity

Tags: java, android, concurrency, synchronization

The Service class will load a library and it takes about 4-5 seconds for the library to become ready. What is the best way to make MainActivity to keep checking on the status of a static boolean in Service class and do something when it's ready? I looked around and knew that using busy wait loop is bad.

The outline of my planned MainActivity is

onCreate - start the service

onResume - show the splash screen until a specific boolean in Service become true then switch to another fragment

Comment: Broadcast an action on library load complete. And receive it in Activity . Also maintain the state in `Service` so whenever next time `Activity` is open it can access the current state .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is `Broadcast Reciever` Try this

```
BroadcastReceiver broadCastNewMessage = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // do your stuff here

        }
    };
```

Now in `onCreate()` register this

```
registerReceiver(this.broadCastNewMessage, new IntentFilter("bcNewMessage"));
```

And in `onDestroy()`

```
unregisterReceiver(broadCastNewMessage);
```

Now Call this method from the `service class` where u want to update the `activity`

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent().setAction("bcNewMessage"));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a broadcast receiver from the Service to your MainActivity which triggers a method inside the MainActivity... instead of constantly checking a static bool in the service.

But you want to be very sure to handle cases where it never loads for whatever reason, otherwise users will be staring at a splash screen forever.

Comment: You should use a LocalBoardcastReceiver. Then send the intent from the service....when ready to tell the Activity to update it's UI. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html